# Pyspark column selection method difference

Tags: pyspark

I am kind of confused about `col` function. I know that I can use the following methods to select a column

- `df.select(df.key)`
- `df.select(col("key"))`
- `df.select(df["key"])`
- `df.select("key")`

So, what are their differences?

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("C", 3)], ["key", "value"])

df.show()
+---+-----+                                                                     
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|  A|    1|
|  B|    2|
|  C|    3|
```

Comment: there is no difference between using `col` and just providing the name within [`select`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.select.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-select). `select` can accept strings as well as expressions.

Answer (score 0):

df.select(df.key)
  df: modify when dataframe name is changed
  key: no space, no special character

df.select(col(key))
  col(): need import pyspark.sql.functions.col

df.select(df[key])
  df: modify when dataframe name is changed

df.select(key)
  no problem